# Delete rows with specific symbol from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, delete-row

I am cleaning my data and here an example of one of my data.frames with column `V1`:

```
    V1
    #title 8132
    river Rhine
    #rows 1231
    #ID 11
    #format csv
    YYYY-MM-DD;hh:mm;   Original;     tested; Flag
    1926-10-01;--:--;    106.400;    106.400; -999
    1926-10-02;--:--;     84.560;     84.560; -999
    1926-10-03;--:--;     72.800;     72.800; -999
    1926-10-04;--:--;     65.800;     65.800; -999
    1926-10-05;--:--;     72.800;     72.800; -999
    1926-10-06;--:--;     72.800;     72.800; -999
    1926-10-07;--:--;     92.960;     92.960; -999
    1926-10-08;--:--;    126.000;    126.000; -999
    1926-10-09;--:--;    153.720;    153.720; -999
    1926-10-10;--:--;    136.920;    136.920; -999
```

I simply need to remove any rows with '#' (i.e. 1,3,4,5) and any rows without '#' contained between rows with '#' (i.e. 2).

Here my expected output:

```
YYYY-MM-DD;hh:mm;   Original;     tested; Flag
1926-10-01;--:--;    106.400;    106.400; -999
1926-10-02;--:--;     84.560;     84.560; -999
1926-10-03;--:--;     72.800;     72.800; -999
1926-10-04;--:--;     65.800;     65.800; -999
1926-10-05;--:--;     72.800;     72.800; -999
1926-10-06;--:--;     72.800;     72.800; -999
1926-10-07;--:--;     92.960;     92.960; -999
1926-10-08;--:--;    126.000;    126.000; -999
1926-10-09;--:--;    153.720;    153.720; -999
1926-10-10;--:--;    136.920;    136.920; -999
```

I tried:

```
df = df[!df$V1 == '#']
```

and

```
df = df[-grep("#", df$V1),]
```

and

```
df_sub = subset(df, V1 != '#')
```

but it does not work.

pleas help, thanks.

Comment: Can you use `skip=` in `read.table()` ? i.e. `read.table(..., skip=6, ...)`

Comment: Why don't you use `sep=';'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did:

```
#read csv file, add 5 columns and convert blank spaces to NAs
df = read.csv('file.csv', header = FALSE, sep = ';', col.names = c('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'), na.strings = '')

#then remove rows which contain NAs
df = df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Hope you will find it useful and apologies if I was not able to reproduce a good data.frame example.